# Bootstrap features not working properly in Angular

Tags: css, angular, node-modules, bootstrap-5

I am trying to make bootstrap accordion items but it is not working properly as in bootstrap doc or youtube tutorials.

I have added bootstrap and jquery for both test and architect/build to angular.json as you can see.

```
       "styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.css"
       ],
       "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", 
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
       ]
```

I have imported bootstrap in styles.css.

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

Also, both of node_modules and src folders are available in same app file.

My html file as below:

```
<div class="container p-5">
<h1 class="text-center mt-5 mb-5">Angular 12 Bootstrap 5 Accordion with Dynamic Data</h1>
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample"><!--ngfor loop started for dynamic data -->
    <div class="accordion-item" *ngFor="let item of selectedData; let i = index">
      <h2 class="accordion-header" [id]="'heading'+i">
     
        <button class="accordion-button" [ngClass]="{ 'collapsed': i != 0 }" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-bs-target]="'#collapse'+i" aria-expanded="true" [attr.aria-controls]="'collapse'+i">
          Accordion Item {{i}}
        </button>
      </h2>
      <div [id]="'collapse'+i" class="accordion-collapse collapse" [ngClass]="{ 'show': i == 0 }" [attr.aria-labelledby]="'heading'+i" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-body">
          <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Accordions dont do anything when i pressed and dont have any styles.
[It looks like this when running the app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vu44.png)

How can i fix this? Thank you.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using jQuery in an Angular app _or_ a Bootstrap 5 app. Also, why aren't you using one of the Angular implementations of Bootstrap?

Comment: actually im not familiar with front end development so i imitate the codes on the web, mostly. how can i use Angular implementations of Bootstrap? If you mean ng-bootstrap, i copied accordion implementation from documentation but it didnt seem same.

Comment: I do mean ngBootstrap. It's the same except for syntax, because it's implemented via Angular components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated my bootstrap version to 5.1.3 and it worked!